# How can I extract these list and tuples into strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have these lists and tuples and can't figure out how to extract the numbers out of them.

```
[('40', '50')] [('35', '45', '49')] [('02', '11')]
```

They are stored in three different variables, how can I extract them? I've tried the following:

```
chain.from_iterable(list_one)
```

but it gives me this:

```
<itertools.chain object at 0x1101415f8>
```

Expected output for `[('40', '50')]` is `40 50`

Expected output for `[('35', '45', '49')]` is `35 45 49`

Expected output for `[('02', '11')]` is `02 11`

Comment: strings. I want to print them out..

Comment: Can you please provide the expected output for your example lists?

Comment: what is the input like? Currently you have three list literals in your question. Are they part of a  tuple?

Comment: I've added the expected output for each. and they are tuples inside lists.

Answer (score 2):

Use **[`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)** to chain your lists together and then iterate through them. Then you can unpack in the `print` call to get every sub-element element printed out.

So, if for example your lists are named `l1`, `l2` and `l3` as so:

```
l1, l2, l3 = [('40', '50')], [('35', '45', '49')], [('02', '11')]
```

You're able to access each individual and print it with:

```
for sub in chain(l1, l2, l3):
    print(*sub)
```

Yields:

```
40 50
35 45 49
02 11
```

Now, the output from your original attempt, namely:

```
<itertools.chain object at 0x1101415f8>
```

is due to the fact that `chain` returns an *iterator* object and that is its representation in the Python REPL. Remember, iterators are meant to be iterated over.

Answer (score 0):

To get each seperately as string:

```
 output = ""
    a = [('02', '11')]
    for i in a:
        for x in i:
            output = output + " " + x
```